# Copper anode dissolves in electrolysis of copper sulfate solution

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, electrolysis

I did an experiment with copper sulfate where you place two copper rods in an aqueous solution of copper sulfate. You apply an electric current and copper metal builds up on the cathode. I noticed that the copper anode dissolved. Does the dissolved copper from the anode just turn into more copper sulfate? If not, what does it produce?

This is NOT a homework question. It’s an experiment that I performed out of pure curiosity.

Comment: What happened to the cathode?

Comment: In my question, I said that copper built up on it. I probably should have added that it didn’t dissolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have replicated electro-rafination of copper. Copper ions from the being dissolved anode are replacing the copper ions being deposited on the cathode.

Therefore overall electroneutrality of the solution is kept. The local neutrality is managed by electromigration of both ions $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-}$.